# Probability of getting same percentage overlap between 2 datasets

Tags: r, probability

I have 2 datasets containing proteins from 2 independent experiments, and these datasets have 72% of proteins in common. How would I work out the probability in R that, if randomly shuffled, the overlap would be 72% again (and how could I represent this graphically)?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd expect the overlap to be less than 72% because some of the matching proteins will end up in the same dataset.

Comment: What exactly would be randomly shuffled?  The union of the records from the two datasets?  What would be done about duplicates within each of the new datasets?  Indeed, do any of the original datasets contain duplicates? It sounds like you don't need a "shuffle" but rather want to sample twice, independently and without replacement, from the union of all records.